# Failed to Restrict Special Characters in EditText with inputType = typePassword

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a login form in my android application, the problem is when I entered `special characters` it bypass all my checks. I meant to say its log in thru **invalid password** and redirect to next activity. I had used *`android:digits`* property of **EditText**. it works fine on simple **EditText** but not working when I set `inputType` property.

**xml:**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:id="@+id/edt_signup_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm" 
    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:maxLength="15"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />
```

how can I restrict the special characters when `android:inputType="textPassword"` . Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this via java would be to use a Regex.

You would define what characters you want to allow like such:

```
final static String INPUT = "[ a-zA-Z0-9_-]+";
final static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(INPUT);
```

This `INPUT` pattern would allow space, underscore, dash, 0-9 and lower and upper case letters.

Then to check the inputted text against the pattern you would use the following:

```
Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(textView.getText().toString());
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        //login here
    }
    else {
        //do something else
    }
```